# My CSS works in the inline section but not as an external stylesheet

Tags: css, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I am currently trying to use CSS to stylize my application in Apex 5. The problem I am having is that when I write my CSS code in the "inline" section of any page in the application, then the CSS code works, but if I write the CSS code on Notepad and then upload the file and reference the file within my application, then the CSS code does not work. I have written several lines of CSS code, so I'll just post one small section of it as a sample so that you all can see my format:

```
body{
  font: bold 12px/16px "Times New Roman";
}
```

I have uploaded the file in the Static Application Files section of the Shared Components page of the application. I have then tried referencing the file in different places, such as at the page level and user interface level, but nothing has worked so far. I'm very new to CSS, so any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After uploading the file have to be displayed in the list of static files. The list of files have a column `Reference`, which contain a string like this: `#APP_IMAGES#test.css`. Copy this string and put it, for example, on the page in the section `CSS` - `File URLs`. This should work.

Then make sure that file reference works. Open your page and take a look on a list of CSS files. The same functionality is present in all browsers, but it is accessible by different ways. In IE:

- Press <kbd>F12</kbd>.
- Open `Network` tab.
- Press "Enable network traffic capturing" (a green triangle in the left top corner).
- Reload the page. A list of files appears.
- Find your file in a list:

  - If the file is not present, then you copied an incorrect link, or you copied it into an incorrect place, etc.
  - If the file is present, normally it should have status `200` (the `Result` column). If a status is not `200`, there could be a lot of reasons (depending on the status).
  - If the file is present with the status `200`, your `CSS` property doesn't work, because it is overridden with another `CSS`. To define with which one, go to the `Dom Explorer` tab.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did everything you said, and the file was present on the "Network" tab, but the status was 404 in the result column. How do I fix that?

Comment: @KatherineReed This error is quite hard to fix without access to the system. Sorry, can't say the exact 100% solution. The problem could be in many places - typo in APEX, a problem with a web server, with a filesystem, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your help! It appears to be a problem with the server. Working on fixing that now, so hopefully that should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach:

1. On server, go to `ORACHE_HOME/apex/images/css` (path can be different, but you can find it by .css extension)
2. Put you file here
3. Id editor, in page properties, go to the CSS -> File URLs section
4. Write path like this: `/i/css/new.css` (i - in general, alias for your images directory)